# Slick 3.0.0 upgrade - default projection using generic column type

Tags: scala, upgrade, slick

I have a table definition with generic column working in Slick 2.1.0 but could not make it work in 3.0.0, details of table structure below.

```
abstract class SomeTable[V](tag: Tag, schemaName: String, tableName: String)
extends Table[(String, Int, Date, Timestamp, V)](tag, Some(schemaName), tableName) {

  def entityKey = column[String]("ENTITY_KEY")

  def someId = column[Int]("SOME_ID")

  def someDate = column[Date]("SOME_DATE")

  def someTime = column[Timestamp]("SOME_TIME")

  def someValue: Rep[V]

  def * = (entityKey, someId, someDate, someTime, someValue)
}
```

Error Details -

```
[error]  found   : (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Int],    slick.lifted.Rep[java.sql.Date], slick.lifted.Rep[java.sql.Timestamp], slick.lifted.Rep[V])

[error]  required: slick.lifted.ProvenShape[(String, Int, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp, V)]
```

I believe the cause of error is "someValue" which is generic type and could not resolved into ProvenShape.

Please let me know any suggestions to resolve this error. Thanks.

Comment: Same here... the example doesn't work http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to get the code to compile by changing to:

```scala
abstract class SomeTable[V](tag: Tag, schemaName: String, tableName: String)
extends Table[(String, Int, Date, Timestamp, V)](tag, Some(schemaName), tableName) {

  def entityKey = column[String]("ENTITY_KEY")

  def someId = column[Int]("SOME_ID")

  def someDate = column[Date]("SOME_DATE")

  def someTime = column[Timestamp]("SOME_TIME")

  def someValue: Rep[V]

  def *: ProvenShape[(String, Int, Date, Timestamp, V)] = proveShapeOf(entityKey, someId, someDate, someTime, someValue)
}
```